# MvvmCross Databinding Not working as expected

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am currently experiencing a weird issue with MvvmCross on android. I want to data bind a a view to a ViewModel. My setup is as follows

```
public class ForumTopicItemsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<ForumReplyListModel> _forumComments;
    ForumTopicDetailsModel _topic;
    long _forumId;
    long _topicId;
    bool _busy;
    int _page;

    public ForumTopicItemsViewModel()
    {
        _topic = new ForumTopicDetailsModel()
        {
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
            Discussion = "Just the fact that I dont care about what is displayed here",
            ForumId = ForumId,
            TopicId = TopicId,
            Topic = "Another Heading, Just for the sake of it"
        };
        _forumComments = new ObservableCollection<ForumReplyListModel>
        {
            new ForumReplyListModel()
            {
                CreatedBy = "Peter Edike",
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                Reply = "Just a reply to show how far I have come"
            }
        };
    }

    public int Page
    {
        get { return _page; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _page, value); }
    }

    private static bool IsHostReachable()
    {
        var nReachability = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxReachability>();
        return nReachability.IsHostReachable(AppConfiguration.RequestUrl);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ForumReplyListModel> Comments
    {
        get { return _forumComments; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _forumComments, value); }
    }

    public ForumTopicDetailsModel  Topic
    {
        get { return _topic; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _topic, value); }
    }

    public string Heading => this.Topic.Topic;
    public string Description => this.Topic.Discussion;
    public string DateCreatedString => this.Topic.DateCreatedString;

    public bool Busy
    {
        get { return _busy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _busy, value); }
    }

    public long ForumId
    {
        get { return _forumId; }
        set {SetProperty(ref _forumId, value); }
    }

    public long TopicId
    {
        get { return _topicId; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _topicId, value); }
    }

    public void Init(long TopicId, long ForumId)
    {
        this.TopicId = TopicId;
        this.ForumId = ForumId;
    }
}
```

and I have the Android XML View Like So

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:MvxBind="Refreshing Busy; RefreshCommand LoadReplyCommand">
                <MvxRecyclerView
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_commentlist"
                    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Comments;" />
            </MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4px"
                android:background="@color/grey_soft" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                        android:textColor="@color/upload_photo_button_color"
                        app:MvxBind="Text Heading" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                        app:MvxBind="Text Description"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_dark" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2px"
                        android:background="@color/grey_soft" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        app:MvxBind="Text DateCreatedString"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/upload_photo_button_color"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Problem:

The contents of the `MvxRecyclerView` are never displayed even though i made sure that the collection had items in the constructor.

Every other binding works as expected. If I however comment out everything except the `MvxRecyclerView`, it becomes visible.

Please I think I did something wrong.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

None of your LinearLayout's seem to have an orientation set. I think the default one is set to `Horizontal` meaning your layout flows from left to right and go outside of the visible area of your screen.

Also another problem is that your layout is awfully nested, meaning it will probably have a significant amount of overdraw and extra measurement passes when it is going to be drawn on the screen. You can un-nest it by using a single `RelativeLayout` instead of the 4 nested layers of `LinearLayout`.

Something like this might work:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:MvxBind="Refreshing Busy; RefreshCommand LoadReplyCommand">
        <MvxRecyclerView
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_commentlist"
            app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Comments" />
    </MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_above="@+id/heading_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4px"
        android:background="@color/grey_soft" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/heading_card"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textColor="@color/upload_photo_button_color"
                app:MvxBind="Text Heading" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                app:MvxBind="Text Description"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2px"
                android:background="@color/grey_soft" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
                app:MvxBind="Text DateCreatedString"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="@color/upload_photo_button_color"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```